# Question about Banach Limit

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, hahn-banach-theorem

I just studied the Banach Limit $\Lambda$ in my Functional Analysis class and I am trying to answer the following question

> Can one define a generalised limit for bounded functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?

For now, I constructed a functional $\mathcal{L}$ from the space $\mathcal{B}$ of bounded linear functions to $\mathbb{R}$ in the following way:

- notice that every real sequence $(x_n)_n$ can be seen as a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$;
- notice that the set $S=\{s \text{ such that } s:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}, s \text{ bounded}\}$ forms a subspace of $\mathcal{B}$;
- use Hahn-Banach Theorem to define a linear functional $\mathcal{L}$ extending $\Lambda$ from $S$ to all $\mathcal{B}$ and such that
  $$
  |\mathcal{L}(f)| \leq \|f\| \quad \text{ for every } f \in \mathcal{B}.
  $$

Such functional is linear and normalized by construction, and positivity is pretty straightforward. I am having trouble with shift invariance. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess $S$ is a *quotient* of $\mathcal{B}$,  rather than a *subspace*,  correct?

That is, we may define a *projection* mapping
$\pi :\mathcal{B}\to S, $
by letting $\pi (f)$ be the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb N$, for every $f$ in $\mathcal B$.

Choosing a Banach limit $\Lambda :S\to \mathbb R$, we  then define  $\mathcal{L}$ to be the composition
$$
  \mathcal B \quad {\buildrel \pi \over \longrightarrow} \quad S \quad {\buildrel \Lambda \over \longrightarrow} \quad \mathbb R.
  $$
The OP has already observed  that this functional has all of the required properties, except possibly for translation invariance.

Denoting by $T_y(f)$ the translation of $f$ by $y$,  namely
$$
  T_y(f)|_x =  f(x-y),
  $$
the missing property is thus
$$
  \mathcal L(T_y(f)) = \mathcal L(f).
  \tag 1
  $$
Observe however  that $\Lambda $ is invariant by integer translations, so this  easily implies that
(1) holds provided $y$ is an integer number.  In particular the correspondence
$$
  y\mapsto \mathcal L(T_y(f))
  \tag 2
  $$
is seen to be periodic with period 1.

When desired invariance properties are absent,
it is a common trick in the theory of group representations to average out.  That is,
in order to overcome the above difficulty
let us   define   $\tilde{\mathcal L}$ by
$$
  \tilde{\mathcal L}(f) = \int_0^1 \mathcal L(T_y(f))\, dy.
  $$
Given any $z$ in $\mathbb R$, we then have that
$$
  \tilde{\mathcal L}(T_z(f)) =
  \int_0^1 \mathcal L(T_{y+z}(f))\, dy =
  \int_z^{z+1} \mathcal L(T_{y}(f))\, dy =
  \int_0^1 \mathcal L(T_{y}(f))\, dy = \tilde{\mathcal L}(f),
  $$
where the penultimate  step is due to the periodicity of (2).

It is now easy to see that $\tilde{\mathcal L}$ satisfies all of the required conditions.

Comment: This is so nice! I didn't know about the integral trick.. thank you!

Comment: ..and also, I was sloppy in saying that $S$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{B}$ - thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You are welcome!